# Saving data between steps in the form to complete form later [New Umbraco Forms]

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

Is it possible to access form data between steps? by triggering a workflow or something without submitting the form?

Here is the link to the original post in Umbraco Forum:
[Original Post](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-forms//76578-saving-data-between-steps-in-the-form-to-complete-form-later#comment-76578)

Any help will be more than welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you return the model without submitting the form? Doesn't it still keep the values?